# Selector children jquery

Tags: jquery, selectores

```
<td class="day base-a" data-month="11" data-year="2018" data-day="05" data-maxday="4">
    <label>5</label>
    <div class="price-tot">
        <div class="tb-col">
            <span class="price-cal" ></span>
        </div>
        <div class="tb-col tb-top">
            <span class="cal-moneda"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="precio base-a">15,393</span>
    <span class="llegada">Llegada</span>
    <span class="final">Salida</span>
</td>
```

Con jquery quiero ponerle texto a los span  cal-moneda y price-cal

intenté lo siguiente

```
$elemento.children("div.price-tot").children("span.price-cal").text(price);
$elemento.children("div.price-tot").children("span.cal-moneda").text(settings.moneda);
```

pero no lo setea

Comment: Como estas seleccionando la variable `$elemento`?

Comment: ¿Qué es `$elemento`?

Comment: es el td de la tabla que este seleccionado

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `.children()` solo busca entre los hijos directos del selector.  Intentalo con `.find()` asi:

```
$elemento.find("span.price-cal").text(price); 
$elemento.find("span.cal-moneda").text(settings.moneda);
```